# Blackberry Application with phonegap

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I have done 1 application for mobile in html5 and I have to make .jad or .ota file for blackberry using phonegap. 
* I get 1 error during building app. Its the signing error . How to sign my app using blackberry? How to get blackberry keys in my mac? 
* I get .csj and .csi files from RIM but I dont know detailed procedure for it . So help me out . 
* What is "907 cod file not found error" ? How to overcome that error?.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

BlackBerry has a nice [article on how to request, create, and use Code Signing keys](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html) on Windows XP, Windows 7, and Mac OS.